# Which is faster in c++11: max(a-b, b-a) or abs(a-b)?

Tags: performance, c++11, hardware

In c++11, which one is faster: `max(a-b, b-a)` or `abs(a-b)`?

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: which compiler do you use?

Comment: Fairly pointless question. Depending on the types and compiler and platform, there are many ways this could end.

Comment: Trust your compiler.

Comment: Get yourself some C++11, put these two thingd in and see for yourself.

Comment: Spend your time worrying about integer overflow instead.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I'm using visual studio 2012's compiler.

Comment: How `max` is defined? Is it `std::max` from `<algorithm>`?

Comment: @vladon from `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `godbolt.org`, permalink: https://goo.gl/QmxbDe

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int abs1(int a, int b) {
   return abs(a-b);
}

int abs2(int a, int b) {
  return std::max(a-b, b-a);
}

int abs3(int a, int b) {
 return a > b ? a - b : b - a;
}

int abs4(int a, int b) {
 return a == b ? a : (a > b ? a - b : b - a);
}
```

Result for clang-3.7 x86 with `-O4`:

```
abs1(int, int):                              # @abs1(int, int)
    subl    %esi, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    negl    %eax
    cmovll  %edi, %eax
    retq

abs2(int, int):                              # @abs2(int, int)
    movl    %edi, %eax
    subl    %esi, %eax
    subl    %edi, %esi
    cmpl    %esi, %eax
    cmovgel %eax, %esi
    movl    %esi, %eax
    retq

abs3(int, int):                              # @abs3(int, int)
    movl    %esi, %eax
    subl    %edi, %eax
    subl    %esi, %edi
    cmovlel %eax, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    retq

abs4(int, int):                              # @abs4(int, int)
    movl    %edi, %eax
    subl    %esi, %eax
    jne .LBB3_2
    movl    %edi, %eax
    retq
.LBB3_2:
    jg  .LBB3_4
    subl    %edi, %esi
    movl    %esi, %eax
.LBB3_4:
    retq
```

Obviously `abs` from `cstdlib` will be faster for random numbers.

Comment: code generated by other compilers is different and might result to different conclusions. Only timing the code, in the actual scope of usage, would give a realistic answer.

Comment: @dau_same All compilers are making nearly the same code. I've done benchmarking (using google benchmark), all variants taken near 2-3 ms.

Comment: 2-3 milliseconds for a handful of instructions seems very very unlinkely. Also, how you run your tests is important, do you call the same function multiple times? Do you call abs2 just after abs1? Cache misses will take more time in this case than the computation time you have in either of those functions.

Comment: @dau_sama Google benchmark runs same function continously several million times. Anyway, benchmark of such a small functions will be incorrect because of resolution of cpu clock and because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to say. It is a pointless test. also running million times the same function does not reflect the use case of the question. CPU clock is accurate if you get the ticks with rtdsc (on x86) and you use that instead. Google benchmark probably does it differently.

Comment: @dau_sama You asked for timing test, I made it :-) For such a little pieces of code less simple arithmetic instructions and jumps means less time.

Comment: in theory, yes, in practice maybe :-) CPUs nowadays have become basically non deterministic machines with all the OOO execution and pipelining.

Comment: @dau_sama In practice there is no need to think about such microoptimizations. OP may freely use what is semantically fits his need. That is `std::abs`.

Answer (score 4):

Time, as a metric, is really only useful in the context of change. Here you're looking for changes to occur through computation in a shorter amount of time, but perhaps ultimately the most significant kind of state change that can occur is within ourselves. Life is really just about experiencing time (which is ultimately about experiencing change), and it's often shorter than we wish it to be. We can only experience so many changes in a finite amount of time, as finite time means finite changes.

So I would suggest that the most efficient solution here is to use a profiler, and in hindsight, after you've written the code in a way that's as straightforward as you can make it (until you have a good reason not to). To grab a profiler and get in the habit of measuring is probably the most effective state change that can occur in the shortest period of time to achieve more efficient computation. That would be, by far, the most efficient solution.

Here is a picture of Jessica Alba to illustrate:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As with all performance related questions, there is only one real answer.
You need to time it on your platform, on your use case. 
Different stl implementations could also implement those functions in different ways, and your CPU architecture in this case plays a big role as well.

Measure it, and get your own conclusions. I bet you won't really notice any significant difference. I am curious on your use case though, why is this so important for you?

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

max:

```
2 substraction: a-b, b-a
1 comparation: a-b>b-a ? a-b : b-a
```

abs:

```
1 substraction: a-b
1 comparation a-b>0 ? a-b : -(a-b)
```

and compare with 0 is simplier than compare two values

So I would tell `abs` is faster as far as `a,b` are primitive data types

Comment: The thing labeled "1 comparation[sic]" hides more operations, unless you want abs to be a primitive (which is a fair assumption *sometimes* but you don't seem to make it)

Comment: Why not `a > b ? a - b : b - a`? Or even `a == b ? a : (a > b ? a - b : b - a)`.

Comment: I have used max definition as follows: `max(x,y) = x>y?x:y` and then I have passed the parameters: `x=a-b, y=b-a`, the same with `abs(x) = x>0?x:-x`. Of course, you have made it shorter but this won't compiler do I expect @vladon

Comment: @maskacovnik All this difference will be simply optimized out by any modern compiler.